# Phonegap fileTransfer.Download is not working error code 3

Tags: android, cordova, download, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

In my apps running phonegap cordova 3.5 on android 4.4, using the file-transfer plugin to upload files works well but dowloading create an exception. I tested on the device and on the emulator blueStacks
this code works fine with cordova 2.9 but when I update the cordova to 3.5 dowloading create an exception

the download function:

```
download = function () {    
    viewModel.popup_download.visible(false);
    loadPanelVisible(true);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
      fileSystem.root.getFile(viewModel.file_download_name(), {create: true, exclusive: false}, function() {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
        uri="https://api.exemple-exemple.com/api/Dav/Download/"+path+"/"+viewModel.folder_downlod();
        filePath=currPath+"/"+viewModel.file_download_name();

        ft.download(uri,filePath,win_download,fail_download,false, {
                headers: { 
                   "HeaderUserData": JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Token: token }),
                   "HeaderDavData": JSON.stringify({ UserName: viewModel.userId_dav(), Password: viewModel.userPassword_dav() }),
                }
        });

      }, fail);
    }, fail); 
}
```

Comment: l'exception :{"target":"file:\/\/\/mnt\/sdcard\/windows\/PublicPictures\/Box-BV-Blanche.jpg",
"source":"https:\/\/api.phosphorus-technologies.com\/api\/Dav\/Download\/dossier1\/Box-BV-Blanche.jpg",
"http_status":200,
"code":3}
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.cordova.PluginResult.<init>(PluginResult.java:52)
at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$4.run(FileTransfer.java:798)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

Answer (score 3):

you got problem in spaces and special chars, you must use encodeURI before you send the request.

```
download = function () {    
viewModel.popup_download.visible(false);
loadPanelVisible(true);
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
  fileSystem.root.getFile(viewModel.file_download_name(), {create: true, exclusive: false}, function() {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
    uri="https://api.phosphorus-technologies.com/api/Dav/Download/"+path+"/"+viewModel.folder_downlod();
    filePath=currPath+"/"+viewModel.file_download_name();

    uri = encodeURI(uri);

    ft.download(uri,filePath,win_download,fail_download,false, {
            headers: { 
               "HeaderUserData": JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Token: token }),
               "HeaderDavData": JSON.stringify({ UserName: viewModel.userId_dav(), Password: viewModel.userPassword_dav() }),
            }
    });

  }, fail);
}, fail);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable currPath is never defined, and I don't think you want to use it at all. You passed your download folder from the viewModel, so then get the folder result in the callback.

```
download = function () {    
    viewModel.popup_download.visible(false);
    loadPanelVisible(true);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
      fileSystem.root.getFile(viewModel.folder_downlod(), {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(filePath) { // ADD PARAMETER HERE
        var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
        uri="https://api.phosphorus-technologies.com/api/Dav/Download/"+path+"/"+viewModel.folder_downlod(); //IS THIS A VALID URL ENDING IN THE FOLDER NAME?
//REMOVE FILE PATH HERE
        ft.download(uri,filePath,win_download,fail_download,false, {
                headers: { 
                   "HeaderUserData": JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Token: token }),
                   "HeaderDavData": JSON.stringify({ UserName: viewModel.userId_dav(), Password: viewModel.userPassword_dav() }),
                }
        });

      }, fail);
    }, fail); 
}
```

It worries me that you construct your API call ending with a folder, because this code will only work to download a single file. I think it may just be that the naming is inconsistent.

Comment: filePath=currPath+"/"+viewModel.folder_downlod();                      the currPath is the path of the file in the device                            the viewModel.folder_downlod() is the name of the file  in the device              target":"file:///mnt/sdcard/windows/PublicPictures/Box-BV-Blanche.jpg"‌​  where I chose to make the download file

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. For clarity, you should rename the method `folder_download` to `file_download` or (even better) `download_filename`

Comment: ok I edit it. this code works fine with cordova 2.9 but when I update the cordova to 3.5  dowloading create an exception

Comment: when you call `fileSystem.root.getFile()`, it will give you the path to the file on the device in the callback.  Add filepath as a parameter and remove this line `filePath=currPath+"/"+viewModel.file_download_name();`

Comment: fileSystem.root.getFile()gives only the path of the root but the currPath gives the current folder path  before calling download function I choose the path where I download the file        currPath =data.fullPath;